# Changing the Export-CSV output output format

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am working on a PowerShell script that will output a list od system admins to a CSV file using the `Export-Csv` command.  The portion of the script that gets the data is:

```
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
  $Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Quiet
  if ($Online -eq "True"){
    $GroupName = Get-WmiObject win32_group -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.SID -eq 'S-1-5-32-544'} | Select-Object name -ExpandProperty name
    $LocalGroup =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$GroupName"
    $GroupMembers = @($LocalGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
    $Members = $GroupMembers | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    foreach ($Member in $Members){
      $obj = New-Object System.Object
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $Computer
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AdminGroupMembers" -Value $Member
      $obj
    }
  }
}

}

Get-Admins | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\scripts\adm.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

The current output is formatted looks like this:

```
"Computer1", "Admin1"
"Computer1", "Admin2"
"Computer1", "Admin3"
"Computer1", "Admin4"
"Computer2", "Admin1"
"Computer2", "Admin2"
"Computer3", "Admin1"
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
"Computer1", "Admin1" , "Admin2" , "Admin3" , "Admin4"
"Computer2", "Admin1" , "Admin2"  
"Computer3", "Admin1" , "Admin2" , "Admin3"
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output format is not CSV, so `Export-Csv` is not a suitable tool for you. Try this instead:

```
Get-Admins | group { $_.Computer } | % {
  '{0},{1}' -f @($_.Group.Computer)[0], ($_.Group.AdminGroupMembers -join ',')
} | Out-File 'output.csv'
```

For PowerShell v2 you'll need to manually expand the group properties:

```
Get-Admins | group { $_.Computer } | % {
  $computer = @($_.Group | select -Expand Computer)[0]
  $admins   = ($_.Group | select -Expand AdminGroupMembers) -join ','
  '{0},{1}' -f $computer, $admins
} | Out-File 'output.csv'
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion however The file does output to a csv file, just not in the format I would like it.  You suggestion above runs but provides no CSV output which is a requirement.

Comment: @user2654059 Now it does.

Comment: the output file is 9 lines ling with a comma in each line, no other data.

   
#Export data out and give feedback
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Get-Admins | group { $_.Computer } | % {
  '{0},{1}' -f @($_.Group.Computer)[0], ($_.Group.AdminGroupMembers -join ',')
} | Out-File 'c:\scripts\adm.csv'

Write-Host "`n Script completed for online systems"

Comment: It seems you're still using PowerShell v2. See updated answer.

Comment: Updated the powershell to ver 3.  Pre last edit change produced a 9 line list with the computer name and a comma but no admin names.  Incorporating the latest changes I get this error 43 times:
At C:\Scripts\test.ps1:44 char:27
+   $admins   = ($_.Group | select -Expand AdminGroupMembers) -join ','
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Object:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Apparently you did not name the property `AdminGroupMembers`.